# Android Studio Sample Location

Tags: android, android-studio

As some examples were introduced in older API-Versions and are not included in the new API Samples, i've downloaded API-19 Examples through the Android SDK Manager. However, the Examples are not shown in the "Import Samples Page.

But when i search my machine, i am finding it here:
/Users/myusername/Library/Android/sdk/samples/android-19/legacy

[image]

I've checked the filepath, and there is the api-19 directory present. Is it possible to change the samples directory path?
[image]

Comment: Nothing in your first screenshot indicates that the samples _doesn't_ appear. The first folder under android-19 is named "Background". Can you find the JobScheduler sample under Background? It does appear on my end

Comment: This is just to show, where i am looking for the samples.